# Does the round method from the math class automatically cast expliclity?

Tags: java

From my knowledge Implicit casting happens when converting from a smaller data type to a large one
for example

`double example = 2` which converts an int to a double

Explicit casting however has to be done manually because of data loss right :D

for example  `int exampleExplicit = 2.2;`

The question I wanted to ask all of you is that in the Math class, round method
 `int Question = Math.round (1.1f);` returns an integer of 1, does that mean that this method automatically explicity casts this float number to an integer?

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question but I just needed clarification :D

Comment: `Math.round(float)` returns an `int`. So, whether you want to call what it is doing casting or otherwise, you input a float and get back an int.

Comment: That's an implementation detail you shouldn't really care for, nor that's how you should think about that method. All you should care about is what's explicitly written in the documentation. Having said that the [source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Math.java#L743) for that method is pretty readable if you want to take a look :) (the answer is: in certain cases it does)

Comment: Thank you all for answering and helping, good day

Answer (score 1):

`Math.round(float)` is just a method. What it does is a black box, but you do know that it requires exactly one parameter, which must be of type `float`, it does... something... and then it returns some sort of `int`. The java language specification does not know about its existence, and therefore confers nothing special about how it works or what it does.

Therefore, trivially, given that 'casting' is fundamentally a thing that the language spec covers, **`Math.round(float)` cannot be said to 'implicitly cast'**. It's not about whether it does or doesn't - it's about the notion that the question is nonsense in the first place, therefore no answer is available.

Of course, it's not really a mystery meat sandwich: There is javadoc that explains what it does, and you can trust that the javadoc isn't lying to you. It will return the `int` with the property that the difference between the float value and that integer is the smallest (no other int it could return would claim to have a smaller difference). How does it accomplish this feat?

Who knows. Who cares. It does what it does, and given that its core library, you can assume it does that reasonably efficiently. If you are just intrigued and wanna know how it works - java is open source, so [you can look at the source of `Math.round(float)` right here](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/0af356bb4bfee99223d4bd4f8b0001c5f362c150/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Math.java#L743).

You sound like a beginner, which means it's likely that source makes absolutely not one iota of sense to you.

That's sort of my point: Whilst anything is potentially interesting, if your aim is to become a better java programmer, there is an order to things. If someone has never driven a car and has barely seen any in their life, and they want to learn how, you **do not** start with a 2 week course on the finer details of carburetor design. You don't need to know this in order to drive a car, and without some more understanding of cars and driving in general, you'll constantly be wondering what it's all even for - you're lacking crucial context.

Same here.

`Math.round(float)` does what it does. Don't worry about how, not at this phase of your java career.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question, have a nice day also!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No

Explanation:

The documentation of Math.round() says it **Returns the closest int to the argument**
So `Math.round(1.2f)` will return `1` but `Math.round(1.6f)` will return `2`.

However, both `int i = (int)1.1;` and `int i = (int)1.6;` will assign `1` to i.

Comment: Yeah, if it wasn't for the fact that in certain cases, at least in openjdk, a cast is exactly what it does. So the short answer should really be "it depends", not a flat out "no".

Comment: Thanks everyone